# Passing a String Bean Resource as AllArgsConstructor in Lombok

Tags: java, spring, lombok

I use `@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))` provided by Lombok to pass in all Autowired fields for a constructor. I've a string field which I want to pass in as well. Is there a way to pass in using @RequiredArgsConstructor?

For ex:

I've:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public ClassA {
    private final DependencyA dependencyA;
    private final DependencyB dependencyB;
    private String config; //this won't work.

}
```

Normally I would do:

```
@Component
   public classA {
       @Autowired
       private DependencyA dependencyA;
       @Autowired
       private DependencyB dependencyB;
       @Resource(name = ConfigClass.DEPENDENCY_C)
       private String config;
    }

    class ConfigClass {
        public final static String DEPENDENCY_C = "xyz";

        @BEAN(name = DEPENDENCY_C) 
        public String getDependencyC() {
        }

    }
```

Comment: As a note, as of Spring 4.3 `@Autowired` is not needed if a class has only one constructor. Additionally, consider using `ConfigurationProperties`.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the String is not marked as final. Make it final and it will work.
Please refer https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/RequiredArgsConstructor.html.

```
private final String config;
```

Note: AllArgsConstructor creates all arguments constructor irrespective of final fields.